# Canvas issues when drawing multiple images

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing

As the title says when i try to draw more then 1 image a something weird happens. while it does draw stuff in the correct locations at the correct sizes it only ends up using the last drawn image. So i end up getting the same image 3 times at different locations and sizes while they are supposed to be different images.

This is my code: 
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HTML5 Canvas</title>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>

</head>
<style>
    #canvas:hover
    {
        /*cursor: none;*/
    }
    #canvas
    {

    }
    body
    {
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var keys = [];
var framerate = 1000/60;
var img = new Image();
var x = innerWidth/2 - 150;
var y = innerHeight/2 - 75;
var speed = 10;


var imageArray = 
[
    "sky.png",
    "road.png",
    "car.png"
];


function drawMap()
{

        img.src = imageArray[0];
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,innerWidth,innerHeight/2);
        console.log("Sky Finished Drawing");


    img.src = imageArray[1];
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,innerHeight/2,innerWidth,innerHeight/2);
    console.log("Road Finished Drawing");

    img.src = imageArray[2];
    ctx.drawImage(img,x,y,300,150);
    console.log("Car Finished Drawing");


}

drawMap();

var mouse = {
    x : undefined,
    y : undefined
}

window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){

    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
window.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
setInterval(animate,framerate);
function animate()
{
    if(keys[87]) //W
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth,innerHeight);

        drawMap();

        console.log("W");
        y -= speed;
    }
    if(keys[65]) //A
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth,innerHeight);

        drawMap();

        console.log("A");
        x -= speed;
    }
    if(keys[83]) //S
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth,innerHeight);

        drawMap();

        console.log("S");
        y += speed;
    }
    if(keys[68]) //D
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0,innerHeight/2,innerWidth,innerHeight);

        drawMap();

        x += speed;
        console.log("D");
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created one Image object and used the same one for each src, so it applied only the last image source.

Please create Image object for each image:

```js
function drawMap()
{
  var img1 = new Image();
  img1.src = imageArray[0];
  ctx.drawImage(img1,0,0,innerWidth,innerHeight/2);
  console.log("Sky Finished Drawing");

  var img2 = new Image();
  img2.src = imageArray[1];
  ctx.drawImage(img2,0,innerHeight/2,innerWidth,innerHeight/2);
  console.log("Road Finished Drawing");

  var img3 = new Image();
  img3.src = imageArray[2];
  ctx.drawImage(img3,x,y,300,150);
  console.log("Car Finished Drawing");
}
```